# Python tkinter - label not showing on the 2nd screen

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I created a code with a yes/no question, and if yes, I use an entry box to ask how many. But when I reach to that How many question, the label is not showing and I don't understand why?

Thanks in advance, below is the code:

```
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, ttk, constants
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.focus_force()
root.withdraw()
root.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', True)
yesnob = messagebox.askyesno('Test','Do you have a clue?')
if yesnob == True:
    root2 = Tk()
    root2.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', True)
    root2.wm_title('How many ?')
    nb_b = 0
    title_loop = Label(root2, textvariable = 'How many ?', height = 2, width = 15)
    title_loop.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    entrybox = Entry(root2, textvariable = nb_b, width = 5)
    entrybox.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    def get_data():
        global nb_b
        try:
            nb_b = int((entrybox.get()))
        except ValueError:
            no_int = messagebox.showerror('Error', 'You did not enter a number, try again!')
        root.destroy()
        root2.destroy()
    exit_but = Button(root2, text = 'OK', command = get_data, height = 3, width = 5)
    exit_but.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
    root2.mainloop()
else:
    root.destroy()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the "textvariable" to "text" worked for me:

```
title_loop = Label(root2, text = 'How many ?', height = 2, width = 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

You created the `Label` with the `textvariable` argument. If you change it to `text` the label is shown:

```
title_loop = Label(root2, text= 'How many ?', height = 2, width = 15)
```

`textvariable` can be used in combination with a `StringVar` if you want to have a text that can be changed. If the text is static use the `text` argument.